# Lo-Dash, difference between array and collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, lodash

A glance at the Lo-Dash docs shows that the API falls in to categories of:

1. Arrays,
2. Chaining,
3. Collections,
4. Functions,
5. Objects,
6. Utilities,
7. Methods,
8. and Properties

A more detailed look in to the Arrays API shows approximately 30 different methods available that are applicable to arrays.

The Collections API has a few more methods than the Arrays API, and they do not share the same methods.

Within the Collections API, a collection is described as an object that is iterated, and may be an array:

> collection (Array|Object|string): The collection to iterate over.

Also, interestingly, there's a Collections API method `_.toArray` that returns an array from a collection:

> Arguments
>
> collection (Array|Object|string): The collection to convert. Returns
>
> (Array): Returns the new converted array.

Would anyone happen to know a formal difference between an array and collection in the Lo-Dash API? I was under the presumption it was a difference due to Backbone.js, however, am now questioning my reasoning to that end, since the methods may be available elsewhere. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It's a good idea to look at the more elaborate [Underscore.js documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#collections), from which this distinction is derived. It states:

> Collection functions work on arrays, objects, and array-like objects such as `arguments`, NodeList and similar. But it works by duck-typing, so avoid passing objects with a numeric `length` property.

Basically, "collections" are things that implement some kind of "iterable" interface, and they internally use the same iteration method (though Lodash source is a bit more convoluted than Underscore). All the "collection methods" do work both on arrays and objects (and a few more iterable things), while the array methods should only be used on arrays (or maybe everything with `.length` and numeric indices), and the object methods work on any objects.

Answer (score 17):

All Arrays are collections but not all collections are arrays. An Object (i.e. `{k: v, ... }`) is a collection that is not an Array. Many of the iterators can iterate over non-Array collections just fine. In this context you can think of arrays as, more or less, ordered collections that are indexed by consecutive non-negative integers.

For example, both of these work:

```
_([6, 11, 23]).each(function() {
    console.log(arguments);
});
_({ a: 6, b: 11, c: 23 }).each(function() {
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/t8a83/

The arguments that the function gets depend on what sort of thing you're iterating over. If you're iterating over an array then you'd get the element and the index, if you're iterating over an Object then you'd get the value and key.

Comment: Does that mean that all the methods of the Collections API can be applied to arrays, strings, and objects?

Comment: They should work with anything that can be iterated over so yes.

Comment: Thank you @mu is too short!