# How to create Lodash collection

Tags: javascript, collections, lodash

There is a pretty convenient way in `underscore` for creating underscore collection (wrapper on array):

```
var x = _([{"name": "John"}]);
x.findWhere({"name": "John"}); // use any underscore methods now
x; // x is underscore collection, containing one item
```

But `Lodash`'s `_()` creates chain. It's rather inconvenient:

```
var x = _([{"name": "John"}]);
x.findWhere({"name": "John"}); // use any underscore methods now
x; // chain, currently empty
x.commit(); // x is Lodash wrapper, containing one item
```

The question is:

*How to create simple collection in Lodash but not the chain?*

Comment: There's no such thing as a collection type in Lodash. Collection is an abstract type that encompasses any type that it can iterate over.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921647/lo-dash-difference-between-array-and-collection

Comment: So just create an array using normal Javascript syntax.

Comment: @Barmar yes, you are right. Thank you. It is disappointing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `commit()` in the declaration and you'll get the wrapper:

```
var x = _([{"name": "John"}]).commit();
x.findWhere({"name": "John"}); // << this works
x; // wrapper
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It's still LodashWrapper, so we still need to call `commit` every time we add any actions to it.

Comment: Did you try it? `x` behaves the same way in lodash and in underscore in my code sample.`x` is a wrapper in both cases and calling a function on it returns the value directly, no need for other `commit()`. In fact, I don't even need `commit()` for lodash and it makes sense, lodash is supposed to be a drop-in replacement for underscore.